# How do I display website content, without making a specific directory for it?

Tags: php, html, ftp

So, as the title says how do I make a website content page, without making a directory for it, now I don't want just make another .html or .php file, I want something like this: www.mysite.com/index.php/my-actual-content. And most importantly, how do I remove the trailing slashes of the end. There are many topics for that, but none of them work, rtrim, trim, or using the .htcaccess file, but I am pretty sure, that if you make a page after index.php/, there wont be any slashes anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so being so stupid, I realised it’s called url routing...